# Drawing a Retina-resolution Image Reflection

Tags: iphone, ios, graphics, quartz-graphics, retina-display

I'm having difficulty dynamically drawing a reflection of a UIImage at Retina resolution (2x scale). Apple's sample code for drawing reflections was never updated to take advantage of the higher resolution. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: Yes, there's an overload of the method that creates a drawing context, that takes a specific parameter. The original method defaults to a non-retina drawing resolution. Post some of your code so I know I'm talking about the right thing, and I'll go look for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/imagereflection) is a library called ImageReflection that allows for easy reflecting of UIImages. The GitHub page says it is two years old, so I don't know to what extent it conforms to "modern" Objective-C (blocks, ARC, GCD, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a pretty nice library to handle this:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXImageView

It provides a category on UIImage for drawing reflections, and a UIImageView subclass that will automatically apply reflections to any image you set at runtime (it can even do the rendering on a background thread to avoid blocking the UI).